# Can you pass multiple Docker BuildKit secrets at once?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

I have a Docker image I need to build but, in order to build it, I have to use AWS credentials and configs. I've figured out how to pass a singular file as the secret; however, I can't pass multiple secret files for one run command. Is there a way that this can happen?

I pass the credentials like this:
`RUN --mount=type=secret,id=aws,target=/root/.aws/credentials npm run build:prepare`

and I build it like this:
`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t $IMAGE:$TAG --secret id=aws,src=$HOME/.aws/credentials .`

However, I also need to pass my `$HOME/.aws/config` file, how can I pass this as a secret alongside my credentials file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a solution, although I don't know if it's the most concise way to write a docker build command with multiple secret files.

First, you have to specify in your RUN command that there are two secrets with different, unique ids and targets as such:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=credentials,target=/root/.aws/credentials \
    --mount=type=secret,id=config,target=/root/.aws/config \
    npm run build:prepare
```

Then, you can pass them in like this:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build \
  -t $IMAGE:$TAG \
  --secret id=credentials,src=$HOME/.aws/credentials \
  --secret id=config,src=$HOME/.aws/config \
  --no-cache .
```